# gcc 11.2 package in Ubuntu Hirsute?

Tags: apt, gcc, 21.04

Is it planned to add package for gcc 11.2 for Ubuntu Hirsute please?
I see it exists for Ubuntu Impish as listed in https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/devel/gcc-11 but not for Ubuntu Hirsute which is gcc 11.1.
Is is possible to install Impish package on a machine running Hirsute (I use WSL2).
Thanks in advance,
Best regards
Joseph

Comment: Except a few specific softwares like web browsers, for obvious reasons, nothing else is upgraded in a given release.

Comment: »»Is it possible to install Impish package«« : Yes, g++/gcc **only**, (as Impish has the same libc6 version as 21.04) . `gcc, g++` and dependencies are now in "main": One line in /etc/apt/sources.list will do. Don't forget to disable the line immediately after g++ install,  or the OS will die at next package install / update. Info https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fFmLtrLOc3Q2g9MHsXBKTcL-XSEQiyHb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the tip.